# Conda activated environment but I can't see in command line

Tags: bash, shell, anaconda, conda, ps1

I have installed an virtual environment with conda and activate it
with the following command lines

```bash
conda create -n test1 python=2 anaconda

source activate test1
```

or

```
conda activate test1
```

and when I activate it and run `conda env list`, it shows me that this environment is activated

[image]

When I check the execution paths, it seems every thing is ok:

[image]

but problem is that I could not see any `(namyenv)` indicator at the start of the command line in terminal and it seams its do not work very well:

[image]

How can I add this envname at the beginning of the code line?

Comment: This functionality concerns the PS1 of the prompt. It might be worth reading up on this (e.g., [some Unix SE questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5bprompt%5d%20PS1)). Conda has `changeps1`  and `env_prompt` settings that control if and how `PS1` is changed, respectively (see `conda config --describe changeps1 env_prompt`). Unfortunately, behavior can be highly dependent on shell (bash, zsh) and terminal, so you'd need to add details on that to get a more specific answer.

Comment: Thank you so much yes that was ok .I commanded `conda config --set changeps1 True` and fixed

Comment: Worked for me!
Pandas does not set it to show the activated environment in PS1. 
 `conda config --set changeps1 True`

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer for posterity to allow for flagging for duplicates to point to this question.

Using the following command spell seems to work:

```
conda config --set changeps1 True
```